# Сортировка в Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, qsort

Прочел в документации и нигде не нашел объяснения (гуглил без результата), **почему** для реализации сортировки выбран метод слияния (пишут модифицированный, а что именно модифицировано ?), а не Qsort ?

Только из-за устойчивости алгоритма слияния или какие-то особенности работы с памятью в реализации JVM обуславливают этот выбор ?

Ведь Qsort требует значительно меньше дополнительной памяти да и по скорости (при разумной реализации) почти всегда превосходит (если верить Кнуту) MergeSort.

Какие есть соображения на эту тему ?

**UPD**

Ответов больше нет, обсуждение закончено. Всем огромное спасибо.

Просмотр материалов по MergeSort в Wiki навел меня на мысль попробовать реализовать ее (невзирая на предупреждение в Вики о большой сложности алгоритма) без выделения дополнительной памяти размером  O(n).

---

yozh, одна реализация (или минимум реализаций) это мне тоже приходило в голову. Хотелось бы узнать, так ли это на самом деле.

Nikolay Artamonov, а какие еще устойчивые сложностью n*log(n) есть ?  Я сходу не припоминаю.

Тогда уж еще один вопрос, почему не дали выбирать из нескольких (устойчивая/неустойчивая) ? Я имею в виду наличие нескольких алгоритмов в стандартных пакетах. Возможно, что бы путаницы меньше было. И так в Java огромное количество классов-методов.

1) Спасибо за ссылку, буду смотреть (это к комментарию с ссылкой на http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms)

2) Нашел там интересный линк на реализацию в jdk7 - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/tl/jdk/rev/bfd7abda8f79
Обещают замечательные характеристики (по дополнительной памяти max n/2 !) и вообще интересно.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

В стандартной библиотеке Java существует три группы перегруженных методов для сортировки:

1. `java.util.Arrays.sort(prim[], ...)` — для сортировки *массивов примитивов* prim (`int`, `byte`, `char`, и т.д.). Использует алгоритм [быстрой сортировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) (quick sort).
2. `java.util.Arrays.sort(T[], ...)` и `java.util.Arrays.sort(Object[], ...)` — для сортировки *массивов комплексных объектов* произвольного типа `T` или `Object`. Использует алгоритм [сортировки слиянием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC) (merge sort).
3. [`java.util.Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) — для сортировки коллекций. Использует алгоритм сортировки слиянием (merge sort).

Причина, по которой для сортировки коллекций и массивов комплексных объектов выбран алгоритм сортировки слиянием, заключается в том, что данный алгоритм является *устойчивой сортировкой*, в отличие от быстрой сортировки, являющейся *неустойчивой*. [Устойчивой сортировкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) называется такой алгоритм, который сохраняет порядок следования элементов с одинаковыми ключами сортировки. К примеру, пусть нам требуется отсортировать следующие пары чисел по первому числу пары:

```
(4, 2)  (3, 7)  (3, 1)  (5, 6)
```

Тогда на выходе, в зависимости от использованного алгоритма сортировки, мы можем получить два различных результата:

```
(3, 7)  (3, 1)  (4, 2)  (5, 6)   (порядок сохранен)
(3, 1)  (3, 7)  (4, 2)  (5, 6)   (порядок изменен)
```

В первом случае пары (3, 7) и (3, 1) с равными ключами сортировки остались в том же порядке следования, как и изначально. Во втором случае они поменялись местами.

Почему важна устойчивая сортировка? *Она позволяет производить цепочку последовательных сортировок, добиваясь сортировки в группах и подгруппах коллекции*. Покажем, что это означает, на примере (примеры записаны на языке Scala для минимизации избыточного кода, присущего Java, но смысл будет ясен). Пусть мы имеем структуру данных для представления музыкальных записей:

```
// `albumName` - имя музыкального альбома;
// `trackNumber` - номер трека в альбоме.
case class Record(albumName: String, trackNumber: Int)
```

Разместим в списке несколько музыкальных произведений (из дискографии группы Metallica) в произвольном порядке:

```
val records = List(Record("Master of Puppets", 7), Record("Load", 4),
                   Record("Load", 2), Record("Reload", 5),
                   Record("Load", 3), Record("Reload", 3))
```

Теперь отсортируем записи по номеру трека:

```
scala> val byTrackNumber = records.sortBy(_.trackNumber)
byTrackNumber: List[Record] = List(Record(Load,2), Record(Load,3), Record(Reload,3), Record(Load,4), Record(Reload,5), Record(Master of Puppets,7))
```

А затем отсортируем еще раз, но уже по имени альбома:

```
scala> byTrackNumber.sortBy(_.albumName)
res4: List[Record] = List(Record(Load,2), Record(Load,3), Record(Load,4), Record(Master of Puppets,7), Record(Reload,3), Record(Reload,5))
```

Что мы получили? Мы получили список записей, отсортированный по имени альбома, а в каждом альбоме отсортированный по номеру трека! Для этого мы сначала применили сортировку по менее значимому ключу (номер трека), которая сортирует для нас записи в подгруппах (альбомах). Затем сортировку по более значимому ключу - имени альбома. Такая последовательность важна. Следует заметить, что этот результат можно было бы получить, если сразу отсортировать записи по альбому И номеру трека за один раз, но существуют ситуации, когда нам неизвестны заранее все ключи, по которым мы будем сортировать коллекцию. К примеру, пользователь программы может выбрать в графическом интерфейсе сначала сортировку по полю "номер трека", а только затем по полю "альбом".

В случае, если бы мы применили нестабильную сортировку, вышеуказанный результат не гарантирован. Почему тогда для сортировки примитивов используется быстрая сортировка, являющаяся неустойчивой? Потому что равные примитивы (числа, символы) неотличимы друг от друга при перестановке, в отличие от комплексных объектов. Иными словами, примитивы можно сортировать только по одному ключу (их значениям). Поэтому для них допустимо применить более быстрый алгоритм, коим и является быстрая сортировка.

Comment: Отличный ответ! Наглядно, просто и понятно

Comment: Хороший ответ (первым эту мысль подтвердил @yozh).

Да, большинство за то, что mergesort выбрана из-за свойства устойчивости, которое отсутствует у быстрой и пирамидальной сортировок. Вопрос экономии памяти (речь о сортировке массивов) в данной ситуации видимо не актуален.

Интересно, что никто не упомянул о естественности (а м.б. и оптимальности) сортировки слиянием для связных списков. Или в отличие от указателей в C, манипулировать ссылками на объекты в Java не удобно ?

Comment: Выдержка из JavaDoc'a для Collections.sort(): This algorithm offers guaranteed n log(n) performance. This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array. This avoids the n2 log(n) performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked list in place. Так что разработчики как раз обходят связные списки стороной путем сброса списка в массив.

Comment: Эти фразы я (думаю и все остальные участники обсуждения) читал. 

Вопрос **почему** выбрано такое проектное решение. 

Посмотрел недавно в 3-м томе Кнута с сортировке связных списков слиянием (освежил память). Для MIX речь идет о n\*log(n)

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Может, это объясняется тем, что разработчики хотели оставить одну реализацию для любых структур данных? То что есть у всех списков - это получение элемента по индексу, которое в связном списке является не эффективным. Честно говоря, не особо разбираюсь в подсчете скорости алгоритма: как вы думаете, может ли это служить объяснением?

Comment: Спасибо за отзывы :) Замечу, что это не вопрос личного мнения, выбрана ли mergesort из-за устойчивости, или нет. Это факт: в документации к методам java.util.Collections.sort() сказано, цитирую: "This sort is **guaranteed to be stable**: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort." Это не просто комментарий, это **контракт** с программистом. Быстрая сортировка (по крайней мере, большинство известных вариаций) **не** является устойчивой, а значит, не может быть использована. Правильный вопрос другой: почему mergesort предпочли всем прочим устойчивым алгоритмам?

Comment: Учитывая, что прочие стабильные алгоритмы, это, к примеру, bubble sort, counting sort, и insertion sort, не показывают такую хорошую производительность, как merge sort, становится понятен выбор разработчиков в пользу последней. Кстати, в Java 7 merge sort сменили на позаимствованный из Питона алгоритм timsort, по сути, ту же merge sort, только с серьезно увеличенной эффективностью для частично-отсортированных коллекций. Подробности тут: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/tl/jdk/rev/bfd7abda8f79

Comment: yozh, одна реализация (или минимум реализаций) это мне тоже приходило в голову. Хотелось бы узнать, так ли это на самом деле. Nikolay Artamonov, а какие еще устойчивые сложностью n\*log(n) есть ? Я сходу не припоминаю. Тогда уж еще один вопрос, почему не дали выбирать из нескольких (устойчивая/неустойчивая) ? Я имею в виду наличие нескольких алгоритмов в стандартных пакетах. Возможно, что бы путаницы меньше было. И так в Java огромное количество классов-методов. Спасибо за ссылку. Нашел там интересный линк на реализацию в jdk7 - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/tl/jdk/rev/bfd7abda8f79

Comment: Вот именно, что в Java и без того хватает большого количества методов и классов, чтобы усложнять все разделением единого Collections.sort() на два варианта: Collections.mergeSort() и Collections.quickSort(), или, более правильно, Collections.stableSort() и Collections.unstableSort(). Такое разделение - излишняя **специализация** для стандартной библиотеки **общего назначения**. Задача Collections.sort() - тупо сортировать коллекции общего назначения, о которых мало что известно, наиболее быстрым **для общего случая** способом, с чем он и справляется более-менее хорошо.

Comment: Что касается других устойчивых алгоритмов сортировки, можете посмотреть вот эту замечательную табличку: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms В ней также указаны оценки времени работы для общего, худшего и лучшего случаев. Из нее видно, что конкурентов у merge sort, вобщем-то и нету.

Comment: все кул, доступно. только что-то ваш код на java не очень похож :)

Answer (score 7):

Сортировка методом слияния используется для массивов (и списков, так как в конечном итоге перед сортировкой списки перегоняются в массивы) объектов. Для сортировки примитивов используется быстрая сортировка. Из этого можно сделать вывод, что дело именно в устойчивости алгоритма: для примитивов она не имеет значения, так как никакой разницы между двумя, скажем, тройками типа `int` нет; в то же время `a.compareTo(b) == 0` не означает, что `a == b`.

Answer (score 5):

Быстрая сортировка неэффективна на упорядоченных массивах(иногда даже переполняет стек вызовов), а MergeSort этого недостатка лишена. Хотя, если верить [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_сортировки):

> ... При использовании O(n) дополнительной памяти, можно сделать сортировку устойчивой ...

Comment: С упорядоченными массивами борются правильным выбором (например медиана из 3-х) разделяющего элемента. Вообще эффективность программирования блока выбора разделяющего элемента (pivot) видимо является определяющей для данного метода сортировки.

Answer (score 2):

Разница в производительности. В лучшем случае сортировка слиянием эффективнее быстрой сортировки. Правда разница в коэффициенте, а не то чтобы очень огромная.

Comment: Расскажите это Д. Кнуту.

Comment: А, ну простите. Не в лучшем, а в худшем случае.

Answer (score 2):

В худшем случае qSort работает за O(n^2), то есть гораздо медленнее, чем в среднем. Merge этим не страдает.

Для объектов, когда операция сравнения становится более весомой (`Comparable.compareTo()` или `Comparator.compare()`), это особенно актуально.

Answer (score 2):

Рандомизированный QSort работает *всегда* за O(n log n). У этого есть вполне строгое доказательство.

А в Java реализована как сортировка именно QSort (с небольшой модификацией: выбираются не один, а два опорных элемента, и массив делится на три части). Вот пример: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[])

Comment: yozh уже указал - примитивы сортируются qSort, объекты - слиянием