# Предлагаю обсудить сортировку слиянием

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, c

**Yamsort yet another stable merge sort with small auxiliary memory**

Некоторое время назад мы обсуждали здесь вопрос [Сортировка в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33385/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-java) и пришли к выводу о том, что в Java используется алгоритм сортировки слиянием из-за того, что в первую очередь это устойчивая (stable) сортировка. Там я высказал идею попробовать реализовать сортировку слиянием (невзирая на предупреждение в Вики о большой сложности алгоритма) без выделения дополнительной памяти размером O(n).

Как это может быть реализовано?

Comment: "5-10% от размера сортируемого массива" - это O(n). mergesort можно и на месте сделать

Comment: Да, среди этих сортировок 2 таких. symmsort и aamsort. symmsort stable, но время N\*(log N)^2, а aamsort unstable, она реально быстрая, но ее надо сравнивать с quicksort.

Comment: @avp, а как ведет себя yamsort и timsort на x86 и x64 если взять, например `long long`?

Comment: @Spectre, к сожалению не сумел изложить кратко. Если будет много желающих (или ХэшКод так посоветует), можно радикально сократить, оставить ссылку на code.google.com . Все материалы там есть.

--

@Dex, а вот сейчас и попробую. Опубликую в **UPD**

--

@Gorets, чем-то ХэшКод мне симпатичней, поконкретней здесь что ли ?
Насчет не место - в определенной мере согласен, ХэшКод позиционирует себя не как место для обсуждений. Но, решил должить о том, что получилось в результате  обсуждения одного моего вопроса здесь.

Comment: Ну, началось... Похоже скоро пора присоединяться к http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow

Comment: Это не вопрос, а скорее блог-пост. Я не вижу, как на него можно конкретно ответить.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko, посмотрите на его дату... Вряд ли мне станет интересно снова погружаться в эту тему.

Comment: Это комментарий к моему голосу за закрытие :)

Comment: Что-то много "закрывателей" появилось. Не думаете, что кому-то кроме Вас (и в какой-то  степени меня) это может все же оказаться интересно? / (ведь подобного метода сортировки в литературе Вы не обнаружите)

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/138146/

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko, Вы так считаете?  А может всем нам лучше относиться к этому сайту, как к личному блогу, страницы которого имеют распределенную природу (IMHO от этого его (сайта) конечная цель -- накопление знаний -- только выиграет).

Comment: @Qwertiy, я знаю этот метод сортировки (называю его в "вопросе" `aamsort `,    мы с его автором даже немного переписывались) и использую среди других, с которыми сравнивается yamsort.  / Разница в том, что yamsort *устойчивая сортировка*, а aamsort (и, скажем, qsort) неустойчивые.

Comment: @avp нет, ни в коем случае! Можете задать свой вопрос на мете, но я гарантирую что там вам скажут, что это против правил сайта. Стэк - это не форум, не блог и не доска на Реддите, он сделан для задавания четких и конкретных вопросов

Comment: @avp: Большая часть сообщества за вас. Вот и всё, что я могу сказать по этому поводу.

Comment: @avp если вопрос - это больше ответ, чем вопрос - переведите его в community wiki. Закрывателей это успокоит.

Comment: @PashaPash, это как? Насколько помню, на ХК под вопросом был текст -- "сделать общим". Теперь ничего похожего я не вижу. / Если можете -- переводите в community.

Comment: @VladD а как вы перевели в общий свой вопрос про книги?

Comment: @PashaPash: Если задать вопрос, есть птичка «сделать общим».

Comment: @VladD у меня нет - только на ответе.

Comment: @PashaPash: У меня тоже почему-то нет сейчас. Но раньше точно была.

Comment: @avp Как мне кажется, в Вашем вопросе все прекрасно, за исключением только одного, он оформлен немножко не по правила SO (от этого и все волнения). Единственное, что я бы хотел Вас попросить - пожалуйста, перенесите все тело вопроса в ответ, за исключением "Yamsort yet another stable merge sort with small auxiliary memory".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, OK. Сейчас попробую все исправить.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, только часть комментариев теперь надо как-то перенести под ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Уважаемое сообщество ! Заранее приношу извинения за объем обсуждаемой темы (*на самом деле это текст был написан в 2012 году  как часть вопроса, но в связи с новыми правилами сайта по рекомендации администрации переделан в ответ*).

Например, вот так. Код на C [здесь](http://code.google.com/p/yamsort/source/browse/)

Здесь предлагаю обсудить реализацию на языке C (на C++ тоже компилируется). Я назвал этот проект **yamsort** (yet another merge sort) и разместил его на code.google.com под названием yamsort ([вот прямая ссылка](https://code.google.com/p/yamsort/) ). В [Downloads](https://code.google.com/p/yamsort/downloads/list) лежат .tar.gz , а в [Source](https://code.google.com/p/yamsort/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk) соответственно файлы в текстовом виде.

Описание в файле Readme.txt , реализация: в yamsort.c функция в стиле qsort(), в yamsort_tmpl.h в стиле C template ([идея отсюда](https://github.com/swenson/sort)). Использование C template функции в файлах int_yamsort.c и data_yamsort.c .

Пример

```
// data_yamsort.c
struct data {
  int  key;
  double d;
};

#define SORT_NAME data
#define SORT_TYPE struct data
#define SORT_CMP(x,y) ((x).key < (y).key ? -1 : ((x).key == (y).key ? 0 : 1))

/*
  make  data_yamsort(struct data a[], size_t n) function
 */

#include "yamsort_tmpl.h" // препроцессор создаст функцию data_yamsort(struct data a[], size_t n)
```

Описание алгоритма

Алгоритм обеспечивает устойчивую (stable) сортировку при использовании небольшого количества (5-10% от размера сортируемого массива) динамически выделяемой памяти. Время работы пропорционально N*log(N), как и обычно в алгоритмах сортировки слиянием, которые в основном используют значительный объем вспомогательной памяти в фазе слияния.

Используем "стандартный" рекурсивный алгоритм сортировки слиянием с делением массива пополам на каждом шаге. Когда отрезок массива становится маленьким (скажем короче 31) сортируем его вставками.

Упорядоченные массивы перед слиянием расположены в памяти последовательно. Идея реализуемого здесь алгоритма слияния заключается в размещении элементов одной последовательности в "очереди", которая по возможности размещается на месте уже вставленных в результат элементов другой последовательности.

Проводим слияние левой и правой частей на месте левой части. Элементы левой части последовательно перемещаются в очередь, которая состоит из динамически выделяемых блоков, размером sqrt(N). Если возможно, блок размещается на освободившемся в правой части месте, иначе выделяется функцией malloc(). Однажды выделенные malloc() блоки при освобождении из очереди заносятся в список свободных и используются повторно. Освобождающиеся блоки очереди, размещенные в массиве заносятся в свой список свободных.

Блоки очереди на месте элементов правой части выделяются последовательно. Если очередной добавляемый в отсортированную последовательность элемент должен попасть в первый из блоков очереди, размещенных в правой части, то этот блок перемещается в свободное место в правой части массива или (свободного места нет) в один из malloc-блоков.

Подробнее о манипуляциях с очередью.

Блок очереди - заголовок и дальше массив данных

```
// Queue block header
typedef struct {
  int fdata, ffree; // индексы первого занятого и свободного элемента data[]
  struct  qblock *next, *prev;
} QBLOCK_HDR;

// Queue block with data array
typedef struct qblock {
  QBLOCK_HDR h;
  SORT_TYPE data[1];
} Q_BLOCK;

// Блок управления очередью и свободными блоками
typedef struct {
  Q_BLOCK *head, *tail, 
    *flist,     // список свободных блоков, полученных malloc()
    *aflist;    // двусвязный список свободных блоков в правой части массива
  void  *ffree, // начало свободного места в правой части
    *falloc,    // первый блок очереди, размещенный в правой части
    *afirst,    // начало всего массива
    *alast;     // его конец
  int   bsize,  // количество элементов, размещаемых в блоке очереди
    totbsz;     // размер блока очереди в байтах
} DATA_QUEUE;
```

При занесении в очередь нового элемента: Пока в последнем блоке очереди есть место, размещаем в нем (в data[]). Иначе достаем новый блок и размещаем в первом элементе data[]. Новый блок получаем следующим образом:

1. Из списка aflist;
2. Размещаем этот блок в свободной части массива данных;
   Это место между блоками очереди уже размещенными в массиве и
   элементами правой части, еще не перемещенными в отсортированную 
   область. Корректируем ffree.
3. Из списка flist; 
   Это список ранее выделенных вызовом malloc() блоков, которые в 
   данный момент не содержат данные очереди.
4. Вызываем malloc();

При выборке элемента из очереди для помещения его в отсортированную последовательность проверяем, не освободился ли блок очереди. Если ставший пустым блок единственный в очереди, то он остается в ней и может повторно заполняться. Иначе, если блок был выделен malloc(), то помещаем его в список flist. Блок из области массива помечаем свободным и помещаем в список aflist.

При занесении элемента в отсортированную последовательность, которая уже достигла правой части массива проверяем не занято ли это место началом какого-либо блока очереди или блока из списка aflist. Если это блок списка aflist, то он просто исключается из списка. Если же это блок очереди, то он копируется в свободное место. В первую очередь пытаемся скопировать его в свободную зону в правой части массива, аналогично пункту 2) в алгоритме занесения элемента в очередь. Иначе копируем этот блок в блок из списка flist, а если flist пуст, то вызываем malloc().

В [.tar.gz](https://code.google.com/p/yamsort/downloads/list) есть программы нескольких сортировок и программа их вызова для измерений (./measure). В Readme.txt об этом более подробно.

---

```
Оценки сортировок:
N - размер массива
            time            aux memory
yamsort     O(N*log(N)) ?   O(sqrt(N))  stable
tim_sort    O(N*log(N))     O(N/3) ?    stable
mmsort      O(N*log(N))     O(N/2)      stable
qsort       O(N*log(N))     O(N)        stable (unstable for huge N)
quick_sort  O(N*log(N))     O(1)        unstable
aamsort     O(N*log(N)) ?   O(1)        unstable
symmsort    O(N*(log(N))^2) O(1)        stable

yamsort
Отношение размера динамически выделенной памяти к объему массива int []
K - количество malloc() блоков размером sqrt(N) для случайных int ключей

array N   array байт  queue K   queue (bytes)/array
1000      4000        4           0.188
5000      20000       6           0.103
10000     40000       7           0.081
50000     200000      13          0.062
100000    400000      17          0.056
250000    1000000     28          0.058
500000    2000000     38          0.055
1000000   4000000     55          0.056
2500000   10000000    84          0.054
5000000   20000000    121         0.054
10000000  40000000    169         0.054
25000000  100000000   264         0.053

Некоторые результаты измерений для массивов int [] и 
struct data {
       int  key;
       double   d;
} []

VmHWMi максимальная резидентная память в KBytes для int [].
timei  время сортировки int [] в миллисекундах.
Costi  "стоимость" сортировки int [] в GBytes*sec (гигобайтосекунды).
VmHWMd  максимальная резидентная память в KBytes для struct data [].
timed   время сортировки struct data [] в миллисекундах.
Costd   "стоимость" сортировки struct data [] в GBytes*sec.

            DATA TABLES

table1 [64-bits] 1000 (4000/16000 bytes max_key_value 2147483646)
                          VmHWMi timei    Costi      VmHWMd timed    Costd   
system qsort                724    0.143      0.104    748    0.104      0.078
libc _quicksort             676    0.081      0.055    684    0.092      0.063
template yamsort            688    0.057      0.039    700    0.062      0.043
template Swenson tim_sort   688    0.057      0.039    712    0.067      0.048
template mmsort             684    0.040      0.027    700    0.046      0.032
template symmsort           672    0.098      0.066    688    0.102      0.070
template Swenson quick_so   672    0.040      0.027    684    0.044      0.030
template aamsort            680    0.052      0.035    688    0.059      0.041

table2 [64-bits] 5000 (20000/80000 bytes max_key_value 2147483646)
                          VmHWMi timei    Costi      VmHWMd timed    Costd   
system qsort                752    0.420      0.316    876    0.638      0.559
libc _quicksort             692    0.488      0.338    748    0.561      0.420
template yamsort            700    0.360      0.252    768    0.407      0.313
template Swenson tim_sort   712    0.328      0.234    800    0.380      0.304
template mmsort             704    0.247      0.174    800    0.294      0.235
template symmsort           688    0.768      0.528    748    0.819      0.613
template Swenson quick_so   688    0.244      0.168    744    0.260      0.193
template aamsort            696    0.297      0.207    748    0.346      0.259

table3 [64-bits] 10000 (40000/160000 bytes max_key_value 2147483646)
                          VmHWMi timei    Costi      VmHWMd timed    Costd   
system qsort                792    0.900      0.713   1032    1.400      1.445
libc _quicksort             708    1.050      0.743    828    1.120      0.927
template yamsort            720    0.810      0.583    856    0.920      0.788
template Swenson tim_sort   736    0.710      0.523    908    0.830      0.754
template mmsort             732    0.530      0.388    916    0.660      0.605
template symmsort           704    1.720      1.211    832    1.870      1.556
template Swenson quick_so   704    0.530      0.373    828    0.570      0.472
template aamsort            712    0.660      0.470    828    0.750      0.621

table5 [64-bits] 100000 (400000/1600000 bytes max_key_value 2147483646)
                          VmHWMi timei    Costi      VmHWMd timed    Costd   
system qsort               1496   11.400     17.054   3840   21.900     84.096
libc _quicksort            1060   12.800     13.568   2236   13.500     30.186
template yamsort           1096   10.400     11.398   2348   11.800     27.706
template Swenson tim_sort  1236    9.000     11.124   2868   11.000     31.548
template mmsort            1264    7.100      8.974   3028    8.500     25.738
template symmsort          1060   22.700     24.062   2236   24.500     54.782
template Swenson quick_so  1060    6.500      6.890   2228    7.000     15.596
template aamsort           1068    7.500      8.010   2240    8.800     19.712

table7 [64-bits] 1000000 (4000000/16000000 bytes max_key_value 2147483646)
                          VmHWMi timei    Costi      VmHWMd timed    Costd   
system qsort               8532  132.400   1129.637  31968  211.800   6770.822
libc _quicksort            4572  149.200    682.142  16296  156.400   2548.694
template yamsort           4744  130.700    620.041  17132  144.500   2475.574
template Swenson tim_sort  6124  108.200    662.617  22316  131.400   2932.322
template mmsort            6540   86.600    566.364  24124  111.000   2677.764
template symmsort          4576  279.300   1278.077  16300  319.000   5199.700
template Swenson quick_so  4576   77.200    353.267  16296   85.500   1393.308
template aamsort           4584   88.400    405.226  16300  108.700   1771.810

table23 [64-bits] 10000000 (40000000/160000000 bytes max_key_value 2147483646)
                          VmHWMi timei    Costi      VmHWMd timed    Costd   
system qsort              78804 1550.000 122146.200 313184 2606.000 816157.504
libc _quicksort           39684 1707.000  67740.588 156880 1778.000 278932.640
template yamsort          41776 1499.000  62622.224 165200 1771.000 292569.200
template Swenson tim_sort 54792 1206.000  66079.152 216912 1552.000 336647.424
template mmsort           59200 1010.000  59792.000 234984 1320.000 310178.880
template symmsort         39688 4272.000 169547.136 156884 4556.000 714763.504
template Swenson quick_so 39692  893.000  35444.956 156884 1002.000 157197.768
template aamsort          39696 1031.000  40926.576 156884 1355.000 212577.820

Несколько странные результаты для 32-bit

table1 [32-bits] 1000 (4000/12000 bytes max_key_value 2147483646)
                          VmHWMi timei    Costi      VmHWMd timed    Costd   
system qsort                620    0.117      0.073    636    0.136      0.086
template yamsort            556    0.062      0.034    556    0.084      0.047
template Swenson tim_sort   552    0.108      0.060    552    0.106      0.059
template mmsort             556    0.034      0.019    552    0.056      0.031

table2 [32-bits] 5000 (20000/60000 bytes max_key_value 2147483646)
                          VmHWMi timei    Costi      VmHWMd timed    Costd   
system qsort                640    0.679      0.435    672    0.907      0.610
template yamsort            552    0.451      0.249    552    0.514      0.284
template Swenson tim_sort   556    0.581      0.323    556    0.651      0.362
template mmsort             556    0.252      0.140    556    0.373      0.207

table5 [32-bits] 100000 (400000/1200000 bytes max_key_value 2147483646)
                          VmHWMi timei    Costi      VmHWMd timed    Costd   
system qsort               1272   19.800     25.186   2844   35.700    101.531
template yamsort            820   12.300     10.086   1872   16.800     31.450
template Swenson tim_sort  1120   17.200     19.264   2144   20.400     43.738
template mmsort            1080    8.400      9.072   2268   18.200     41.278

table7 [32-bits] 1000000 (4000000/12000000 bytes max_key_value 2147483646)
                          VmHWMi timei    Costi      VmHWMd timed    Costd   
system qsort               8220  254.400   2091.168  23952  413.100   9894.571
template yamsort           4700  169.200    795.240  12964  222.900   2889.676
template Swenson tim_sort  5876  215.100   1263.928  16732  283.400   4741.849
template mmsort            6360  115.800    736.488  18096  205.500   3718.728

table23 [32-bits] 10000000 (40000000/120000000 bytes max_key_value 2147483646)
                          VmHWMi timei    Costi      VmHWMd timed    Costd   
system qsort              78488 2952.000 231696.576 234752 4758.000 1116950.016
yamsort                   41696 4899.000 204268.704 123840 5085.000 629726.400
timsort                   54660 5305.000 289971.300 162772 6281.000 1022370.932
mmsort                    58896 3501.000 206194.896 176112 4576.000 805888.512
symmsort                  39624 8536.000 338230.464 117768 11543.000 1359396.024
libc _quicksort           39624 2604.000 103180.896 117508 2714.000 318916.712
template yamsort          41696 1978.000  82474.688 123840 2367.000 293129.280
template Swenson tim_sort 54656 1948.000 106469.888 162780 3110.000 506245.800
template mmsort           59164 1323.000  78273.972 176112 2307.000 406290.384
template symmsort         39624 5242.000 207709.008 117772 8721.000 1027089.612
template Swenson quick_so 39624 1518.000  60149.232 117768 1664.000 195965.952
template aamsort          39624 1131.000  44814.744 117768 2694.000 317266.992
```

Мое краткое резюме: практический интерес yamsort представляет для сортировки очень больших массивов в условиях дефицита физической памяти в системе.

Код свободный. Может кому-нибудь удастся улучшить (изменить) его и получить практическ важный результат.

Еще раз приношу свои извинения за объем, но надеюсь, что многим эта тема будет интересна. Если кто-то сможет разумно отредактировать это безобразие, уменьшив в несколько раз (но оставив информативным), то я буду только благодарен ему.

И конечно же, по ходу разработки возникло несколько вопросов.

*Первый вопрос*:

Как объяснить, что на 32-bit yamsort быстрее timsort, а на 64-bit наоборот ?

Лично я ума не приложу. Гонял все на Linux в виртуалках. Запуск на Linux без виртуалки, на 64-bit машине модулей, сделанных на 32 и 64-bit виртуалках показал то же самое. Т.е. цифры другие (там CPU другой), а характер данных не изменился.

*Второй*:

Мне подсказали, что алгоритм может быть интересен в области embedded system. Что Вы думаете по этому поводу ?

**UPD 1**

Сравнение  `long long []` template C timsort с yamsort (по просьбе @Dex)

```
             1000  5000  10000 30000 100000  3000000 1000000 5000000 10000000
ll_tim_sort  0.062 0.334 0.713 2.508 8.983   28.76   110.37  592.6   1241
   kB        704   744   800   1016  1792    3980    11528   54800   108840
   Cost      0.043 0.248 0.571 2.548 16.09   114.5   1272    32474   135136
ll_yamsort   0.058 0.365 0.811 2.666 10.375  35.45   130.35  745.7   1560
   kB        692   732   768   940   1524    3156    8884    41792   82936
   Cost      0.040 0.267 0.623 2.506 15.78   111.9   1158    31164   129422
```

Можно заметить, что отношение времени выполнения yamsort/timsort растет с 0.93 до 1.25. Это видимо свидетельствует о том, что время yamsort немного хуже N * log N. Наверное сказывается перекопирование блоков очереди, размещаемой в памяти массива. Однако по критерию стоимости `память \* время` (это если бы мы платили за каждый мегабайт RSS, занятый в течении секунды) yamsort более экономичен для длинных массивов.